# Is there an alternative to eval for this code

Tags: python

The processing below is meant to parse the variable `dealList` to populate 4 dictionaries SHD and C. I think the problem is in the penultimate line of the code in which I use `eval(suit)` where suits are looped through.

All the suits SHD, and C are initialized as empty dictionaries, but are meant to eventually contain 13 dictionary items, one for each card in its suit.

I suspect what is happening is that each time eval(suit) is executed it finds a dictionary to process but does not keep the name of the dictionary, so the desired named dictionary is not updated. Stated differently, it looks like I am iterating through a loop using the letter `S` taken from a list, but that letter also names a dictionary. But I don't know how to tell python the two are associated.

What do I need to use instead of eval(), or in addition to eval() to accomplish my goal?

```
keys = list('23456789TJQKA')
values = range (13)
suitDict = {}
for key,value in zip(keys, values):
   suitDict[key] = value
dealList = 'AQJT5.KQ.8.KQT95 3.A765.QT743.843 974.T93.J92.AJ62 K862.J842.AK65.7'.split()
players = list('NESW')
suits = list('SHDC')
S = H = D = C = {}
playerHand ={}
for player,hand in zip(players,dealList):
    playerHand[player]=hand
    print player,hand
    for suit,cards in zip(suits,playerHand[player].split('.')):
       print "SC:",suit,cards
       for card in cards:
           eval(suit)[suitDict[card]]= player
           print "card",card,"Suit",suit,"X",eval(suit),"card",suitDict[card],"player",player
```

Perhaps a listing of output will show the problem. Notice in the sample output listing below, the first 5 cards are spades and the next 2 cards are hearts, the K and Q of hearts, to be specific. But the spades dictionary is being altered, not the hearts dictionary. This lack of change of the array that is being updated continues forever.

```
N AQJT5.KQ.8.KQT95
SC: S AQJT5
card A Suit S X [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 'N'] card 12 player N
card Q Suit S X [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'N', 11, 'N'] card 10 player N
card J Suit S X [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'N', 'N', 11, 'N'] card 9 player N
card T Suit S X [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'N', 'N', 'N', 11, 'N'] card 8 player N
card 5 Suit S X [0, 1, 2, 'N', 4, 5, 6, 7, 'N', 'N', 'N', 11, 'N'] card 3 player N
SC: H KQ
card K Suit H X [0, 1, 2, 'N', 4, 5, 6, 7, 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'] card 11 player N
card Q Suit H X [0, 1, 2, 'N', 4, 5, 6, 7, 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'] card 10 player N
SC: D 8
card 8 Suit D X [0, 1, 2, 'N', 4, 5, 'N', 7, 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'] card 6 player N
SC: C KQT95
card K Suit C X [0, 1, 2, 'N', 4, 5, 'N', 7, 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'] card 11 player N
card Q Suit C X [0, 1, 2, 'N', 4, 5, 'N', 7, 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'] card 10 player N
card T Suit C X [0, 1, 2, 'N', 4, 5, 'N', 7, 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'] card 8 player N
card 9 Suit C X [0, 1, 2, 'N', 4, 5, 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'] card 7 player N
card 5 Suit C X [0, 1, 2, 'N', 4, 5, 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'] card 3 player N
E 3.A765.QT743.843
SC: S 3
card 3 Suit S X [0, 'E', 2, 'N', 4, 5, 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'] card 1 player E
SC: H A765
card A Suit H X [0, 'E', 2, 'N', 4, 5, 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'E'] card 12 player E
card 7 Suit H X [0, 'E', 2, 'N', 4, 'E', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'E'] card 5 player E
card 6 Suit H X [0, 'E', 2, 'N', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'E'] card 4 player E
card 5 Suit H X [0, 'E', 2, 'E', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'E'] card 3 player E
SC: D QT743
card Q Suit D X [0, 'E', 2, 'E', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'E'] card 10 player E
card T Suit D X [0, 'E', 2, 'E', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'E'] card 8 player E
card 7 Suit D X [0, 'E', 2, 'E', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'E'] card 5 player E
card 4 Suit D X [0, 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'E'] card 2 player E
card 3 Suit D X [0, 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'E'] card 1 player E
SC: C 843
card 8 Suit C X [0, 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'E'] card 6 player E
card 4 Suit C X [0, 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'E'] card 2 player E
card 3 Suit C X [0, 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'E'] card 1 player E
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the cause of your issue, but `S = H = D = C = {}` almost certainly doesn't do what you want. It makes all those names references to the same dictionary. I'm guessing that you want them each to be separate dictionaries.

Comment: That is exactly the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code oddity is mainly caused by the fact that all your suit dictionaries (`S`, `H`, `D` and `C`) are referencing the same dictionary. You need to initialize them separately if you want them to point to a different reference (e.g. `S, H, D, C = {}, {}, {}, {}`).

That being said, `eval` is (almost) never a solution. In your case, I'd do something like:

```
keys = list('23456789TJQKA')
values = range (13)
suitDict = {}
for key,value in zip(keys, values):
    suitDict[key] = value
dealList = 'AQJT5.KQ.8.KQT95 3.A765.QT743.843 974.T93.J92.AJ62 K862.J842.AK65.7'.split()
players = list('NESW')
suits = {"S": {}, "H": {}, "D": {}, "C": {}}
playerHand = {}
for player,hand in zip(players,dealList):
    playerHand[player] = hand
    print player,hand
        for suit,cards in zip(suits,playerHand[player].split('.')):
            print "SC:",suit,cards
            for card in cards:
                suits[suit][suitDict[card]] = player
                print "card",card,"Suit",suit,"X",suits[suit],"card",suitDict[card],"player",player
```

That being said, I think you're over-complicating your case...

Comment: You don't need _suits.keys()_ under _zip_ - just _suite_ will do. Most iterable modifiers - e.g., _sorted_, _list_, _set_, etc. - handle dictionary keys under the hood. In Python 2.* _keys()_ will produce intermediate list; in Python 3.* it's just redundant code.

Comment: True that. I removed the redundancy.

Comment: Yes. It took me a while to see that you replaced the `eval()`, which is desirable. Do you mean that even another alternative would simplify this more? For example, I am considering defining suits SHD & C as range(13)'s, (lists, not dicts), and using suitDict[card] which is an integer index into the suit lists in my `eval()` process.  If I do so, I *think* I need to revert to my original `eval()` process, but that works to make SHD&C into lists, which is sort of pleasing to me. Comments?